# Why the same data is adding in the useState array of object in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on an react app where i am fetching data from firebase databse and then saving that data in an useState array of objects now the problem is that every other data field is saving perfectly but one field is saving with the same data for every object i am fetching.

here is the code :

```
  useEffect(() => {

      const RecentUsers = () => {

        const usersRef = ref(dbref, 'RecentChatWeb/' + curUser.uid);
        onValue(usersRef, (snapshot) => {
        
        //array for storing the keys
        const recentUserIds = [];

        //Getting the keys and   
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const recentkey = doc.key;
        recentUserIds.push(recentkey);

**        HERE I AM FETCHING AND SAVING MESSAGES IN MSG VARIABLE
**        **const msg = doc.child("message").val()**

               
        const fetchData =  async()=> {
         
          const recentUserDocs = [];
        
          for(const userIds of recentUserIds){

            const q =  query(collection(dataref, "Users"), where("uid", "==", userIds));
            const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
          
              querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                console.log(doc)
                recentUserDocs.push({
                 id: doc.id, **message : msg,**
                 recentUser: doc.data() });
               }); 
            }
          
              setRecentUsers(recentUserDocs)         
        };

        fetchData()
        });

    });  
       }
   
      RecentUsers()
     },[curUser])
```

So In the above code i am feteching and saving the messages in msg variable and then saving the msg variable in the array recentUserDocs in the recentUserDocs.push method. and then in the setRecentUsers i am setting the complete data in the useState RecentUsers but here all data is saving fine but the message value is showing same for all the object. While i want to save it according to every user. but it is not saving please guide me how can i do it.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, you should move the message retrieval and assignment inside the loop where you iterate over querySnapshot

```
useEffect(() => {
  const RecentUsers = () => {
    const usersRef = ref(dbref, 'RecentChatWeb/' + curUser.uid);
    onValue(usersRef, (snapshot) => {
      const recentUserIds = [];

      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const recentkey = doc.key;
        recentUserIds.push(recentkey);

        const fetchData = async () => {
          const recentUserDocs = [];

          for (const userIds of recentUserIds) {
            const q = query(collection(dataref, "Users"), where("uid", "==", userIds));
            const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
              // Fetch the message inside this loop
              const msg = doc.child("message").val(); // Assuming "message" is a child of the current document
              console.log(doc);
              recentUserDocs.push({
                id: doc.id,
                message: msg, // Assign the correct message
                recentUser: doc.data(),
              });
            });
          }

          setRecentUsers(recentUserDocs);
        };

        fetchData();
      });
    });
  };

  RecentUsers();
}, [curUser]);
```

the msg variable is now being fetched and assigned inside the loop where you iterate over querySnapshot. This ensures that the correct message is associated with each user,

Comment: harsh brother but the msg is coming from top loop message does not exists where you have move the variable message